# NPM can't install/uninstall any packages

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I can't able to install/uninstall any npm package due to this error Cannot find module 'emoji-regex'. Any idea what went wrong? .below are my configurations. And I tried npm install emoji-regex, this also giving error
[image]
NPM- 6.14.4
Angular CLI: 11.0.6
Node: 12.16.3

Comment: can you do `npm install emoji-regex` ?

Comment: What does it mean? Are you not able to install or install the package emoji-regex or are you not able to install any packages because emoji-regex can't be found?

Comment: @ChauGiang  npm install emoji-regex also giving above error

Comment: can you please provide full output?  can you install anything else - or does everything fail to install?    what does your .npmrc look like?

Comment: @batman567 added  full output

Comment: it looks as though your repo has gotten bent out of shape.  agree with suggestion below - delete node_modules, clear cache (or at least verify).  then re-install

Comment: Please don't post text as image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow these steps

```
1. Remove package-lock.json file
2. remove node_modules folder
3. npm cache clean --force
4. npm install
```

and please make sure if you are under any organization network, turn on the required firewalls and use proper registry inside .npmrc file